# can't find in string created from String.fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, string, indexof, jszip

I'm trying to parse `AndroidManifest.xml` from apk using JSZip,
I got an Uint8Array and convert it to string using the following code:

```
var zip = new JSZip(fileBlobAsByteArray);
var androidCompress = zip.files["AndroidManifest.xml"];
var androidNonCompress = androidCompress._data.getContent();
var androidText = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, androidNonCompress);
var packageName = androidText.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').indexOf('package');
```

I tried to use toLowerCase and remove all white spaces.

I'm getting a string which I can see it's content in my console but when I'm searching for a word inside the string using indexOf it always returns -1.

I guess the problem is that the output is probably not a regular string and the chrome console doing some manipulation in order to present it as string. the same manipulation I want to do.

Comment: do you mean to use androidText.toLowerCawse.replace ? or do you want toLowerCase().replace

Comment: @JohnBoker I edited the question

Comment: This isn't really solvable, if the string contains `package` the `indexOf` method should work, and since we have no idea what the string looks like, there's no way to answer this ?

Comment: To add to adeneo's comment, you need to work backward and ask for the specific step that you can't do. Have you inspected the value of `androidText` to see if it contains the substring `"package"` or not? Have you checked that `androidNonCompress` is the kind of value you expect? You say you're doing some logging; how/where are you doing that and what is the output?

Comment: @adeneo package name always appears on AndroidManifest.xml, I also can see it on console

Comment: @apsillers package name always appears on AndroidManifest.xml, I also can see it on console

Comment: Well, we can't see it in our consoles, and if I do `"abcpackage12   3".toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').indexOf('package');` it returns `3`, like it should, so it's working just fine, the string clearly does not contain what you're looking for if it's returning `-1`.

Comment: @adeneo the problem is that the output is probably not a regular string and the chrome console doing some manipulation in order to present it as string. the same manipulation I want to do.

Comment: That can be easily [**tested**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pk6cLqa/), and it should be just a regular string, so something else is wrong.

Comment: I think the problem you're having is you expect AndroidManifest.xml to be a regular xml file, but it's not.  http://androguard.blogspot.com/2011/03/androids-binary-xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to convert Uint8Array to searchable string

```
// Reading to content to a searchable string
var packageNameArray = [];
var textArray = String(androidNonCompress).split(',');
for (var i = 0, len = textArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (textArray[i] !== 0) {
        packageNameArray.push(textArray[i]);
    }
}

var searchableText = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, packageNameArray).toString().toLowerCase();
```